# How to create a list of items with associated form with Python Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to realize a Flask Website for pre-ordering some products for an association. What I want to do is publishing a web page with forms on witch people can choose a certain amount of a certain product. For that I iterate on a `fake_product_list` and create a form for each item in list.

Exemple :

| Product name | number of item to order |
| --- | --- |
| 'MU' | Select Quantity |
| 'GP' | Select Quantity |
| 'ARE' | Select Quantity |
| 'CLL' | Select Quantity |

commande_initiale.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Commande Initiale</h1>
    <form action="" method="post">
            {% for entry in form.entries %}
                <p>{{entry.quantity.label}}: {{ entry.quantity }}</p>
            {% endfor %}
            <p>{{form.submit()}}</p>
        </form>
{% endblock %}>
```

forms.py

```
class LigneCommande(FlaskForm):
    quantity = IntegerField()

class CommandeInitiale(FlaskForm):
    entries=FieldList(LigneCommande)
    submit=SubmitField('Passer la Commande')
```

routes.py

```
fake_product_list=['MU','GP','ARE','CLL']

@app.route('/commande_initiale', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def commande_initiale():

    fields = []
    for ligne_bcd in fake_product_list :
        ligne_item = LigneCommande()
        ligne_item.quantity.label=ligne_bcd
        ligne_item.quantity.name=ligne_bcd
        fields.append(ligne_item)

    form = CommandeInitiale()
    form.entries = fields
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print(request.form)

    return render_template('commande_initiale.html', title='Commande Initiale',
                           form=form)
```

I can't figure out whats wrong with this code, it return me an AssertionError: Field must be unbound, not a field class as I want to display the html page

Here is the debugger message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_login\utils.py", line 272, in decorated_view
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "\app\routes.py", line 184, in commande_initiale
    form = CommandeInitiale()
  File "\venv\Lib\site-packages\wtforms\form.py", line 208, in __call__
    return type.__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
  File "\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_wtf\form.py", line 87, in __init__
    super(FlaskForm, self).__init__(formdata=formdata, **kwargs)
  File "\venv\Lib\site-packages\wtforms\form.py", line 268, in __init__
    super(Form, self).__init__(self._unbound_fields, meta=meta_obj, prefix=prefix)
  File "\venv\Lib\site-packages\wtforms\form.py", line 51, in __init__
    field = meta.bind_field(self, unbound_field, options)
  File "\venv\Lib\site-packages\wtforms\meta.py", line 27, in bind_field
    return unbound_field.bind(form=form, **options)
  File "\venv\Lib\site-packages\wtforms\fields\core.py", line 376, in bind
    return self.field_class(*self.args, **kw)
  File "\venv\Lib\site-packages\wtforms\fields\core.py", line 926, in __init__
    assert isinstance(unbound_field, UnboundField), 'Field must be unbound, not a field class'
AssertionError: Field must be unbound, not a field class
```

Thanks for your Help !!

Comment: can you provide more details where exactly the error occurs?

Comment: I'm not sure how to give you more information ... is the debugger message suffisant ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found the problem :

I have to replace in forms.py

```
class CommandeInitiale(FlaskForm):
    entries=FieldList(LigneCommande)
    submit=SubmitField('Passer la Commande')
```

with

```
class CommandeInitiale(FlaskForm):
    entries=FieldList(FormField(LigneCommande))
    submit=SubmitField('Passer la Commande')
```

Thanks for watching ;-)